# How can I get my overloaded constructor to accept any numeric type?

Tags: scala, types, constructor-overloading

I have a `CoordVector` class that accepts `Vector[ComplexNumber]`, where `ComplexNumber` is a class I defined elsewhere, and I also have it overridden to accept `Vector[Double]`. But I want the override to instead accept any numeric type in Scala.

Here is my current code

```
case class RealVector(vector: Vector[Double])
case class ComplexVector(vector: Vector[ComplexNumber])

import scala.language.implicitConversions
implicit def dv(vector: Vector[Double]) = RealVector(vector)
implicit def cv(vector: Vector[ComplexNumber]) = ComplexVector(vector)

object CoordVector {
    def apply(components:RealVector):CoordVector = {
        new CoordVector(components.vector.map(c => ComplexNumber(c, 0)))
    }
}

case class CoordVector(val components:ComplexVector) {
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately I can't just replace `Double` with `Numeric`, but is there a simple way to do this without having to create a new `implicit def` and `apply` for each numeric type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this gets at what you're after.

```
class ComplexNumber(a:Double, b:Double) // put here just to make the rest compile

case class RealVector[N:Numeric](vector: Vector[N])
case class ComplexVector(vector: Vector[ComplexNumber])

import scala.language.implicitConversions
implicit def dv[N:Numeric](vector: Vector[N]) = RealVector(vector)
implicit def cv(vector: Vector[ComplexNumber]) = ComplexVector(vector)

object CoordVector {
  def apply[N:Numeric](components:RealVector[N]):CoordVector = {
    new CoordVector(components.vector.map(c =>
      new ComplexNumber(implicitly[Numeric[N]].toDouble(c), 0)))
  }
}

case class CoordVector(components:ComplexVector) {
  ???
}
```

This allows all the underlying number data to be `Double` but you can create `RealVector` instances with a constructor parameter of type `Vector[Int]`, or `Vector[Long]`, or `Vector[Float]`, etc.

Comment: Yes that worked! I actually tried something similar but it didn't work. What I was missing is the `implicitly[Numeric[N]].toDouble(c)` (I just had `c`). Can you please explain why I need that part?

Comment: The compiler knows that `c`'s type is in the `Numeric` family, but little else, so you can't operate on it (`+`, `*`, `/`, etc.) or cast it (`c.toDouble`). But it won't compile unless there is implicit "evidence" in scope that `c` really is `Numeric`. So what you have to do is pull in that "evidence" code and ask it to operate on the value of `c`.